# Three.js (WebGL) Mesh is hidden in Mobile if Camera is close to object

Tags: mobile, three.js, camera

I am facing a problem in my Three.js WebGL project. I have object (created by using **BoxGeometry**).

camera.near = 0.01
camera.far = 10000

In **PC browser there is no problem** even camera is near or far. But I see **meshes are missing** if **camera is close to object in mobile**. I have tried different settings, different browsers, but same problem. 
Anyone have idea what is the main reason?

[image]
[image]

Comment: 0.01 to 10000 is a very large depth buffer. Do you really need it that big? Reducing the size of the depth buffer can help eliminate clipping issues by reducing the precision needed to perform those kinds of calculations. Alternately, you can try setting `logarithmicDepthBuffer` to `true` during your `WebGLRenderer` initialization: `let renderer = new WebGLRenderer( { logarithmicDepthBuffer: true } );`

Comment: sir I have already said I have tried many ways. I even used 1 - 100. I even used 0.1 - 100. But mobile always have problem

Comment: My renderer already have `logarithmicDepthBuffer` set to `true`

Comment: Your post contains no information regarding the current state of your code, how you have tried to fix it, nor the specific devices/browsers experiencing problems. To get the best answer possible, include as much information as possible in your question. Until you do, all comments and answers will be from an essentially blind perspective, and may duplicate what you have already done.

Comment: Now that I have _a little more_ information, consider _disabling_ `logarithmicDepthBuffer`. That feature requires `GL_EXT_frag_depth` as an available extension in your browser, and is not always available on mobile GPUs. With that disabled, see if your smaller depth buffer helps. Beyond that, we are going to _need_ to see _at least_ how you are setting up your renderer, and the materials used in your model.

Comment: Sorry for a little late reply, this worked for me. Thank you so much. Now problem doesn't exists

Comment: I have set `logarithmicDepthBuffer` to `false` and it worked

Comment: I have added this information as an answer. Please accept the answer so readers can see that this question has been resolved, and so they can avoid the same pitfalls you encountered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, the asker indicated indicated that [`WebGLRenderer.logarithmicDepthBuffer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.logarithmicDepthBuffer) was set to `true`.

The functionality behind `logarithmicDepthBuffer` requires the `GL_EXT_frag_depth` extension is available in the browser/GPU. Some mobile GPUs (especially older ones) do not have this feature available.

Disabling the feature by setting the property to `false` (this is also the default value) fixed the issue on the affected devices (confirmed by the asker in the comments).